# How to add menu support to a theme?

Tags: theme-development, menus, navigation

I tried few tutorials. All i think is i should use `register_nav_menus()` and then add the menu in `header.php`

Here is the code i tried in functions.php from this help site itself

```
function my_cool_menu_function(){
  register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => 'Primary Navigation'
  ));
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_cool_menu_function' );
```

In header.php

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

When i tried to check whether any menu is registered with this function `$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();var_dump($locations);`

I got array of size zero. i,e no menu registered.

Am i missing something?

I can able to see few links in frontend which are pages i guess.

I see that `Your theme does not natively support menus, but you can use them in sidebars by adding a “Custom Menu” widget on the Widgets screen.`

So i think above menu is not registered.

What wrong am doing here?

I have added `add_theme_support('nav-menus');` too in `functions.php`

**Updates**

I tried the same above code through plugin then i can able to see the menu. Which mean it is not working with the theme functions.php file. Am not sure why this happens.

Do anyone know this?

Comment: What happens if you use a different hook like init? You also haven't added a container class to the code.

Comment: I second what Brad is saying, change `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_cool_menu_function' );` to `add_action( 'init', 'my_cool_menu_function' );`

Answer (score 7):

Put this pretty much anywhere (ie. functions.php)

```
add_theme_support( 'menus' );
```

Comment: In WordPress 5.3 `menus` is not a feature listed in [`add_theme_support()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L2384) so this code wouldn't have any effect.

Comment: In 5.3.2 its showing up for me when I do this. I noticed it stopped showing a while ago on newer WP versions, maybe they reverted it.

Answer (score 0):

The default fallback for [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) is `wp_page_menu()`. So if you have not set a menu for a specific location and since you aren't changing the `fallback_cb` parameter in your header.php code, then you will see a list of pages. Additionally your `var_dump` will return an empty array. You need to go to Appearance>Menus and create a menu. Then assign it to the primary location.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1. But that is not the issue now i think the menu itself not supported in theme. `Your theme does not natively support menus, but you can use them in sidebars by adding a “Custom Menu” widget on the Widgets screen.`

Comment: But your theme *does* support menus. I've tested your code and can output a menu, so there must be some other conflict or weird coding going on in your theme. Maybe check header.php for strange conditionals. Run a search through all your theme files for the error message.  Are you sure the functions.php that you are editing is the active theme? (Yes I had to ask and have made that error myself)

Comment: No this answer is not correct and has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @helgatheviking, it probably works for you because you are on an older version or your theme adds the support for menu's elsewhere.

Comment: Not sure if that was the case 6 years ago, but you don't have to declare support for menus as they have been automatically supported for a long time. 

OP said this >I can able to see few links in frontend which are pages i guess.

Which is what made me think they were getting `wp_page_menu()` via the default `fallback_cb` paramter of `wp_nav_menu`. Which may _not_ have been the OP's problem, but was a very relevant thing to check, especially considering their `register_nav_menu()` code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try with init

add_action( 'init', 'my_cool_menu_function' );

I did it, and it works for me.

Cheers.

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus